# Who is the creator of a tag if a question is edited to include a new one?

Tags: support, tags

Per the [Taxonomist badge page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist), the requirement for obtaining the badge is:

> Created a tag used by 50 questions.

If I were to edit a post to add a new tag, would I be accredited with the tag's creation or would the system attribute this to the question owner?